# Django: inlineformset widgets throwing error

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi I have a inlineformset form, i need to change **css class** of its fields. I am using widgets to change the class.
However I am get error.

**My form:**

```
createinvoiceformset = inlineformset_factory(serviceinvoice, serviceinvoiceitems,can_delete=True,form=invoiceitemsform,extra=2,widgets={'Quantity': FloatField(attrs={'class':'quantity'})})
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError at /invoice/createinvoice/

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/invoice/createinvoice/
Django Version:     1.8.9
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

Exception Location:     C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py in __init__, line 245
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version:     3.4.0
Python Path:    

['D:\\pythonspace\\tiktant',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django_select2-4.3.2-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.2-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\babel-1.3-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django_classy_tags-0.5.1-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django_datetime_widget-0.9.3-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django_select2_py3-4.2.1-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django_bootstrap3-4.11.0-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Thank in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FloatField is not a widget. You should use NumberInput instead.